# Add new grade type in moodle

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

Is there any way (function, plugin) that can be used to add another grade type.

by default moodle comes with 3 grade types (points, letters, scales)

I'm trying to add another grade type based on color

For example (red, green, yellow), and total grade should be calculated based on repetition if the user has two red, one green the total grade should be red

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself but Rubrics might do this for you.

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Rubrics

There are some other advanced grading methods here

https://docs.moodle.org/39/en/Advanced_grading_methods

And not much to go on but here is a skeleton template for creating a new grading method

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Grading_methods